# Frink tool fails parsing valid regsub syntax

Tags: tcl

I'm using frink 2.2.2p4 to clean up legacy TCL code, and to provide static checking.

It fails on valid TCL syntax:

```
set foo [regsub {regex} $var {sub}]
```

The error message is:

> Missing "variable" part in call of regsub

I can bypass this error by changing the code to:

```
set foo [regsub {regex} $var {sub} junk]
```

However, this breaks my code (foo is no longer set properly)

Is this a known issue with frink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue with frink. The `regsub` syntax with another word after the substitution (which is a variable name to write the substituted string to) is how Tcl used to always do `regsub`, but that was changed years ago (I committed the change in 2002 [according to the logs](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/history/76) of the [change request](http://tip.tcl.tk/76.html)) when it became clear that most people didn't really care about the count of how many substitutions were performed most of the time. It looks like frink was just never updated.

If you're going to use frink anyway (instead of using, say, [nagelfar](http://nagelfar.sourceforge.net/) which is maintained, though that does something a bit different) then you should write that `regsub` call like this:

```
# Old fashioned syntax
regsub {regex} $var {sub} foo
```

Instead of:

```
# Tcl 8.4 or later syntax
set foo [regsub {regex} $var {sub}]
```

Note that the old fashioned syntax isn't going away! There are still a few cases where a count of substitutions is useful (such as when stripping nested parentheses, where the count is good as the condition for a `while` loop).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that frink has become outdated, even against 8.4.  I thought I was going crazy!
The project I'm working on is legacy code, which I want to modify as little as possible (apart from making it tidy).
There are ~100 regsub occurrences which would need to be changed.
I found a workaround using vi/sed.  I'll explain it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using vi/sed.
A substitution adds a "junk" variable to the end of each regsub:

```
:%s/\(\[regsub.*["}].*\)\]/\1 junkk/g
:%s/\(\[regsub.*\$\S\+\)\]/\1 junkk/g
```

The 1st substitution applies if the last field is "var" or {var}
The 2nd substitution applies if the last field is $var

Save the file and run frink.

```
~/bin/frink -enNU -w 250 script.tn > script_clean.tn
```

Afterwards, revert the same substitution to script_clean.tn:

```
:%s/ junkk//g
```

This worked well for me.
The same technique also fixed a similar issue I had with this error message:

> Error : Missing "variable name" part in call of upvar